# How to find email size before sending

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer to send email. I want to get total size of email message before sending it.

With nodemailer, I can get size of email after the email is sent.

is there any way in which i can do size validation before sending email ? 
verify method of Transporter don't have much information.

Comment: The size increases as encapsulation gets further the OSI Model. For email you would need to know all the headers and their value as well as all section of the email, i.e., the stuff that you send is not the stuff someone else receives - there is a lot more stuff to it.

Comment: Agree. I am ok to have size that is determined by RFC. I get the size value in sendMail method of Transporter as part of info object. Basically I want to restrict user from sending email of total size 5 MB.  Wanted to check how I can determine the message size before sending it.

Comment: Oh, that's a different, more practical perspective then.  You could count the bytes in both the plain text and/or html parts. Then combine that with the attachments if any. And that's it.

Comment: Ya, this would be final option.